# How to stop scanning NFC after capturing a NFC message

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

Now I'm new in Android and working on a Mini-App which should read a NFC-tag, get the URL and process it in the next step. If the user scans the same NFC-tag twice, the App should inform the user by a popup that the NFC-tag has been in the list. But now if the user couldn't remove the NFC-tag from the backside of the device VERY quickly, the App will keep on reading the NFC-tag whose URL has been stored in the list. And then the popup will be triggered.

It is very stupid because the user should never be in a big hurry. I have tried some other Apps which could read the NFC-tag and they can handle this situation very well. They just stop scanning the NFC-tag until the user removed the NFC-tag and press the tag onto the backside of the device again. I just wanna ask, how we could stop scanning after detecting a NFC-tag and start scanning again, when the user actually removes tag and try it another time.

This part is now responsible for capturing the NFC message and it needs something else to makes it not only a receiver. Thanks

```
override fun onTagDiscovered(tag: Tag?) {
        val mNdef: Ndef = Ndef.get(tag)
        val ndefMessage: NdefMessage = mNdef.cachedNdefMessage

        for (curRecord in ndefMessage.records) {
            if (curRecord.toUri() != null) {
                // URI NDEF Tag
                val text = curRecord.toUri().toString()
                processNfcTag(text)
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to programmatically stop NFC Tag scanning, only a user via the settings can turn off the NFC hardware.

While you can stop your own App triggering when a Tag is scanned, this is not desirable as other Apps or the System will be triggered instead over the top of your App.

This is all caused by how the user brings the Tag in to range as it is possible for the Tag to briefly coming and out of range triggering multiple times.

What you need to do is instead is just silently ignore any additional triggers (As you are using `enableReaderMode` you can also turn of the notification sound, but you have not shown that).

There are generally three schemes on how to control ignoring a Tag, they are:-

1. Tag ID based.
2. Time based.
3. User interaction based.

Or a combination of any of the three.

The simplest way is to use a global variable in the Activity.

Then in you use that to ignore additional triggers.

some pseudo code example.

```
val nfcProcessing: Boolean = false

override fun onTagDiscovered(tag: Tag?) {

// Are we already processing a Tag
if (nfcProcessing) {
  // Ignore this Tag
  return
}
// We are not processing a Tag
nfcProcessing = true
        val mNdef: Ndef = Ndef.get(tag)
        val ndefMessage: NdefMessage = mNdef.cachedNdefMessage

        for (curRecord in ndefMessage.records) {
            if (curRecord.toUri() != null) {
                // URI NDEF Tag
                val text = curRecord.toUri().toString()
                processNfcTag(text)
                break
            }
        }
    }


// Somewhere else in the code for example when the user dismisses a dialog box then
nfcProcessing = false
```

Or post a delayed runnable to change the variable to false after a set time.

Or instead of a `Boolean` use an `Int` to store the Tag ID and ignore if current Tag ID is the same as the previous Tag ID

Comment: Hi Andrew again) May I ask you please to have a look on my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76594288/android-nfc-presence-delay