# Android NFC presence delay

Tags: android, nfc

I have an app when on one Activity I will start NfcActivity.
NfcActivity perform a bunch tag read operations once Tag is discovered in **onTagDiscovered()** callback.
I'm using **enableReaderMode** approach to get Tag info.

Problem is next:

In case I place SmartCart/Tag under the phone and then open NfcActivity it needs like 5-15 secs to trigger onTagDiscovered() callback.

BUT

In case I don't place SmartCard/Tag under the phone then start NfcActivity and immediately place SmartCard/Tag under the phone - I'll get onTagDiscovered() callback in less then second.

How to deal with that?
Any workarounds?

```
class NfcActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback {

private var nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter? = null
private var tag: Tag? = null
private var isoDep: IsoDep? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    enableReaderMode(this)
}

override fun onPause() {
    disableReaderMode(this)
    
    super.onPause()
}

override fun onTagDiscovered(tag: Tag?) {
    this.tag = tag
    sendCommandArray(commandsBytes)
}

private fun sendCommandArray(apduCommands: List<ApduCommand>) {
    try {
        isoDep = IsoDep.get(tag)
        isoDep?.connect()

        apduCommands.forEach { apduCommand ->
            val result = isoDep?.transceive(apduCommand.bytes)
            
            // do smth with result, update UI 
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // handle exception
    } finally {
        try {
            isoDep?.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}

private fun enableReaderMode(activity: NfcActivity) {
    if (nfcAdapter != null) {
        nfcAdapter!!.enableReaderMode(
            activity,
            activity,
            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A or
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_B or
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_F or
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_V or
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_BARCODE or
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK or
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS,
            null
        )
    }
}

private fun disableReaderMode(activity: NfcActivity) {
    nfcAdapter?.disableReaderMode(activity)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Some of the delay will be due to the time cost of starting an Activity and it calling `onCreate` and `onStart` before calling `onResume`.

You could put in logging in as the first line in `onCreate` and `onResume` to see how long it takes to get to the point of enabling Reader Mode.

It should be possible to `enableReaderMode` as the first line `onCreate` and then set a flag in a global variable which is then checked in `onResume` to make sure it is not started twice on initial activity creation and then flag is unset in `onPause`

This might save a bit of time.

It also might be due to the default polling frequency set on your hardware.

With `enableReaderMode` you can change this with (sorry in Java not Kotlin)

```
Bundle options = new Bundle();
       options.putInt(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_READER_PRESENCE_CHECK_DELAY, 250);
```

then pass `options` as the last parameter of `enableReaderMode` instead of the `null` you have.

You probably don't want to go less than 250 milliseconds with this otherwise it might cause increased battery usage and possibly other issues.

Comment: Will try to enable early in onCreate, thanks.

Comment: Regarding presence delay, default is 125, so you suggest to increase it? here is source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/master/src/com/android/nfc/NfcService.java

Comment: Actually this problem looks like while using enableReaderMode and place tag before call enableReaderMode() Android device can't detect that Tag is presented((

Comment: The default in the Open Source version of Android is not necessary what hardware manufacturers use, there have been reported problems with some hardware using a Broadcom NFC chipset where the delay was set far too short.  In my NFC app I can present the NFC before I start an Activity that enables `enableReaderMode` in `onResume` and it detects the NFC Tag immediately (it takes about 1 second to write data to the detected Tag)

Comment: Good point, thank you dude! May I know app name?) Is it in GP store?

Comment: Do you use synchronization or at least some flag in method where you send commands to Tag?

Comment: Apps not in GP store, given direct to users. Nothing special done other than setting the `EXTRA_READER_PRESENCE_CHECK_DELAY` though I'm `transceive` low level NfcA commands to Ntag 21x Tags not isoDep Tags